# Bootstrap modals not appearing on mobile when called from navbar-right

Tags: html, iphone, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, navbar

I've been banging my head over this one for days.

I have a small web application built off of Bootstrap 3. Within the `navbar-right` div, I have "Log In" and "Sign Up" buttons. On desktops and tablets, when a user taps/clicks on one of these buttons, the appropriate modal dialogue appears.

However, on mobile phones, when the user interacts with the buttons, nothing appears to be happening. My source follows.

*(Snippet from `navbar` div)*

```
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signup-modal">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-modal">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Log In</a></li>
    </ul>
```

*(Snippet from first few lines of the signup modal)*

```
    <div id="signup-modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
            <div class="modal-content">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why it won't open the modal unfortunately, had the same issue myself and tried researching it.

My modal works fine on desktop all the time, but I find that when you link to it like this:

```
<a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">Modal</a>
```

It opens after 3 clicks on mobile (only when not in the navbar-right). Sometimes it opened after 1, but feels buggy.

However, when trying it like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-xl btn-navbar" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Modal</button>
```

It will work everytime. Instantly, and with no delay. It fires everytime when using a button.

What I did for this particular occasion, was use a button, and a custom class, and style it appropriately, as I didn't want it to look like a button in the navbar, I wanted it to function like any other link.

Works like a charm, give it a go.